# In linux environment, can eclipse application open a shared folder

Tags: linux, eclipse

In windows, We can share a folder and we can access that by our system IP address like \10.0.7.155
to do same In Linux , I have installed Samba application. 
steps followed as- https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html
Now I can an access that shared folder, by providing the IP address of system in explorer window (ctrl+L) like 
smb://10.0.7.155

In windows environment, Using my Eclipse application I can access that shared folder when providing the IP address of system in window, but in Linux using my eclipse application, when providing the IP address in window (ctrl+L) then not able to access or locate that shared folder. 
Please let me know, Is the Eclipse application product, can access the shared folder in linux.

Thanks.

Comment: This is off topic here, this place is for _programming_ questions.

Comment: Why don't you mount the share to some mount point (e.g. /mnt/share/) and access this directory from eclipse?

Comment: Thanks .. Absurd-Mind